# How do I get the extended object in php?

Tags: php, object

The problem I have is quite simple, but sadly I haven't been able to solve it, I'm trying to turn a object into another, the code would look like this in java `Creature creature = (Creature)player;` but what would it be in php?

EDIT:
So this is how the object looks in php, note Character have more function I have just cut them out since they aren't important here

```
abstract class Creature{
    abstract function getId();
    abstract function getName();
    abstract function getAttacks();
}

class Character extends Creature{
    private $id;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($id, $connection){
            $this -> id = $id;
            $this -> connection = $connection;
    }
}
```

I want to turn a Character object into a creature object in php, but have no idea how I do that.

Comment: A creature object cannot exist as an object in its own right, because it's purely abstract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP doesn't have static typing, you don't need to do any conversion.

```
$player = new Character(...);
$creature = $player;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I keep forgetting that. I'm mostly a java programmer.